# Set Properties of User Control on Event Using FindControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a user control that is dynamically loaded in the the page load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyControl ctl = (MyControl)LoadControl(controlPath);
    ctl.ID = "mycontrol";
    this.MyControlPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(ctl);
}
```

Front End of the Page:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="MyControlPlaceHolder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

I have an click event on the page that initiates and postback and calls a method where I'm trying to find the control and set some properties:

```
        MyControl ctl = (MyControl)FindControl("mycontrol");
        if (ctl != null){
            ctl.MyProperty = true;
            Response.Write("success");
        }
        else
            Response.Write("fail");
```

This is writing fail after the postback, so it seems like I'm doing something incorrectly in finding the control.  What is the best way to do this?

EDIT:

```
I switched it to MyControl ctl = (MyControl)this.MyControlPlaceHolder.FindControl("mycontrol");
```

This made it so it was finding the control, however, when the control loads after the postback, it appears as though the property is not set.

Comment: There's no need for tags in titles. The tag system takes care of that. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190 for more information

Comment: You should always reload the user control on the Page_init on each post back. they have to be added during init or preinit, because only then will viewstate will be captured and restored properly

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a recursive FindControl implementation because FindControl will only find direct childs. Your control is inserted in a naming container at a lower level. A generic FindControlRecurisve from MSDN:

```
private Control FindControlRecursive(Control rootControl, string controlID)
{
    if (rootControl.ID == controlID) return rootControl;

    foreach (Control controlToSearch in rootControl.Controls)
    {
        Control controlToReturn = 
            FindControlRecursive(controlToSearch, controlID);
        if (controlToReturn != null) return controlToReturn;
    }
    return null;
}
```

[from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y81z8326%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Or, if you only have one specific conatiner like in your sample:

```
MyControl ctl =  this.MyControlPlaceHolder.FindControl("mycontrol");

if (ctl != null){
            ctl.MyProperty = true;
            Response.Write("success");
        }
        else
            Response.Write("fail");
```

**ViewState enable your control**

```
public class MyControl:Control
{
   public bool MyProperty
   {
       get 
       {
           return ViewState["my"] != null? (bool) ViewState["my"]: false; 
       }
       set 
       {
           ViewState["my"]  = value;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: I switched it to the bottom portion and it is writing "success" now, however, after the postback, the property appears to not be set.  So it's finding the control, but the user control is loading as if the properties are not set.

Comment: MyControl needs to store its MyProperty value in it's ViewState and you have to insert your control in Page_INIT event (not in the LOAD event) in the container. The get method of your Control have to read its [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstate(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the code to dynamically add the control into Init instead of load.  I can't be sure but there are a lot of things that happen between Init and Load and if your control is not present and accounted for it may cause issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

You added the Control in the controls collection of a placeholder.
Apart of what control is your dynamically created control, if you want to looking for your dynamically added control in that way you have to do a recursive search starting from the root (maybe the page), so, if you surf over the net, you could find good solutions for that.

Personally I prefer solutions with: generics support and expressed as extension methods, so you could use the solution everywhere. These are some usefull links

1. [Recursive Find Control with generics](http://weblogs.asp.net/palermo4/archive/2007/04/13/recursive-findcontrol-t.aspx)
2. [Recursive Find Control with generics by extension method](http://www.extensionmethod.net/csharp/control/findcontrol-t)
3. [Recursive Find Control with generics by extension method and linq support/example](http://bchavez.bitarmory.com/archive/2008/07/25/recursive-find-control-using-linq.aspx)

hope this helps